# Run JavaScript in WatiN is failed

Tags: javascript, watin

I'm trying to clicking on span element (usual click() does not work) by FireEvent() method:

```
IE.Span(Find.ById("ueiwo-r")).FireEvent("onmouseclick");
```

But I get an error:

> Exception: RunScriptException, RunScript failed Inner: Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80020101

Does anybody know how to workaround this problem?

Here is html snippet:

```
<td class="urMnuTxt">
<span style="white-space: nowrap;">Add New Item
```

I have Win7, IE8 and WatiN 2.0

Comment: And your configuration - IE & Win versions - would be useful. Wild guess is ( IE7 + WinXP ) which is bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: before clicking I put `FireEvent("onmousemove")` then click with the following code:

```
IE.Span(Find.ById("ueiwo-r")).FireEvent("onmousemouve");
IE.Span(Find.ById("ueiwo-r")).click();
```

That works for me.